# Countability of Sets with rational and real numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, real-numbers, rational-numbers

Determine whether it is finite, countably infinite, or uncountably infinite. Justify

$$\Big\{\Big(\frac{m}{2}, \frac{n}{3}\Big) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid  m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\Big\}$$

The set is countably infinite, I'm struggling to write a justified answer.
$(m/2, n/3)$ are rational numbers, so does that mean $\mathbb{Q}^2$ can be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2?$

EDIT: after reviewing hints in the given answer my idea is:

[image]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://pic.plover.com/MISC/symbols.pdf) to format your questions.  You'll get a lot more positive response if your questions are easy to read.  As to the question itself, yes, $\mathbb{Q}^2\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, because $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I looked at your answer and you only showed that $N\to Z$ is a bijection. $Z\times Z$ is the set of *ordered pairs* of integers. You only showed that $N$ and $Z$ has the same cardinality.

Comment: Did I not show Z -> Q is bijective with the two table's below. So do I show N-> Q is bijective the same way I showed N-> is bijective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

A set $X$ is countably infinite if you can construct a bijection between the set of of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ and $X$. 
A bijection is a function $\phi$ which is both [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) and [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function).

So in essence you are looking for a function

$$
\phi:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}, \quad \phi(m,n)=\Big(\frac{m}{2}, \frac{n}{3}\Big), \quad m,n\in\mathbb{Z}
$$

So one way could be to try to prove that the $\phi$ above in a bijection. Since we know that $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is countable (the set of fractions) so there already exists  a bijection $\psi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. But for completeness sake you could also prove this.

Another way to look at it could be to consider the two sets
$$
\Big\{\frac{m}{2}\mid m\in\mathbb{Z} \Big\}\quad \Big\{\frac{n}{3}\mid n\in\mathbb{Z} \Big\}
$$
and determine whether these are countably infinite and try to reason about the countability of the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two countable/not countable sets.

Hope this helped a bit.

Comment: So you were to prove that the ϕ above in a bijection. Do you prove the bijection between Z and Q? Or Z and N and then Q and N? The hint is a great help also.

Comment: @Sue Now I edited a bit, look at it

Comment: So because N -> ZxZ, and ZxZ -> QxQ. And if you proved both statements, then the function is bijective? and you've  constructed a bijection between the set of of natural numbers N and X. So the set is countably inifnite

Comment: Yes. Think of a bijection as a *pairing*. Each element in one set is paired with one and only one element in the other. So they have to have the same cardinality

Comment: Okay thanks!! I'm going to post my attempt to see if i'm correct above.